# Possible to return an image in the Google Actions webhook response?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

From the docs it seems like SpeechResponse is the only documented type of response you can return:

https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/conversation#SpeechResponse

Is it be possible to load an image or some other type of media in the assistant conversation via API.AI or the Actions SDK? Seems like this is supported with api.ai for FB, other messengers:

https://docs.api.ai/docs/rich-messages#image

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today, Google Actions SDK supports Conversation Actions, by building a better Voice UI, which is integrated with Google Home.

Even API.AI integrations with Google Actions can be checked out [here](https://docs.api.ai/docs/actions-on-google-integration), which shows currently no support for images in the response.

When they provide integrations with Google Allo, then in the messaging interface, they might start supporting images, videos etc.

Comment: Yeah - makes sense, Google Home = no display, voice only :) Missed that part since I only have assistant on my phone.

Comment: It is outdated. See the answers below.

Answer (score 1):

That feature seems to be present now. You can look it up in the docs at https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses

Note: But images would be supported only on devices with a visual output. So Google Home would obviously not be able to do it. But the devices with screen do support a card with an image.

Answer (score 0):

Pro Tip: Yes you can

What you want to do is represent your (image/video) as a URL within API.AI and render the URL as a (image/video) within your app

[see working example](https://fastur.com/#media)

Comment: Hey there! Totally - you can do whatever you want with the returned data if you're building your own web/mobile app, I was asking specifically within the context of Google Assistant.